# Appropriate action installing another SQL application at work

Tags: sql

hope everyone are okay...

I need to install any Sofware for the use of SQL. I'm just a begginer and started an online course. We have a account at work called Administrator and the only account has acces to SQL Managment studio 2014. Inside there are multiple databases linked to the external objects for stock contol purposes to collect data and view data, database was created by another company not us. Id like to download an SQL Software to run simple queries. But would need to know if it would affect any other databases or servers inside our network?.. just need to set it up for my local use.

Thanks

Comment: Client software (like SSMS, SQL Developer, Workbench, etc.) shouldn't affect the server's functionality. Just make sure to **only** install the client, as some of Microsoft's products (I'm not sure about others) might try to install the client + server if downloaded the wrong executable.

Comment: Hi EzLo thanks alot for your help!